# Craft cms search multiple fields with query parameter

Tags: craftcms

I would like to use a query term for multiple fields according to their fields' handle in Craft cms 3.5.x, but unfortunately only for field title that works correctly, while for the other fields i get no results at all.

```
             {% if craft.app.request.getParam('q') %}
                    {% set searchQuery = craft.app.request.getParam('q') %}
                    {% set queryEntries = craft.entries({
                       search:{
                       query: 'title:' ~ searchQuery ~ ' OR  appealer:' ~ searchQuery  ~ ' OR  assigner:' ~ searchQuery,
                            subLeft: true,
                            subRight: true
                         }
                        }).all() %}
                {% endif %}

                    {% if queryEntries|length %}
                          <p>{{ queryEntries|length }} results:</p>

                          <ol>
                            {% for entry in queryEntries %}
                              <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </ol>
                        {% else %}
                         <p>Your search for “{{ searchQuery }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
                    {% endif %}
```

Any idea that could help me?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/37966/search-on-multiple-custom-fields-with-a-query-parameter, which I have responded to, please avoid posting duplicates.